# Occasional non-drawing of elements

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am rendering a modest amount of VBOs. And it starts off drawing them all, but occasionally the game will render partial frames, i.e. it will skip the later elements.

I have checked and I am drawing them on the order:

1. Opaque front to back
2. Transparent back to front
3. Then transparent overlay items

It is often these last items don't appear on one of my devices. Note that when this happens all bullet physics bodies are at rest or moving, but it doesn't appear to be down to physics taking a while.

It's as though OpenGL is cutting me off mid frame because I have taken too long. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no lower limit on frame rates.  It's more likely you have exceeded the limits of some driver-internal buffer or it could just be an OpenGL ES driver bug.  I recommend you try it on another device or AVD.